# Can I make my own header field to be used by me and the clients visiting a web-app?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, http-headers

While I used some header fields like :

```
X-AppEngine-Country
X-AppEngine-City
```

( The `X` suggest that they are non-standard header fields. ) I was thinking how can  one implement/setup its own *Http Header Fields* to be used by their client ? The above header fields are defined to be used by the web-apps hosted on google appengine. ~[Ref](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#Request_Headers)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure from your question if you would like to force the client to send you these custom headers or set these custom headers in the response from the server.
If you are using REST API using Java implementation of JAX-RS (Jersey) then it is fairly simple to get the headers from the request or set the headers on the response.
The example below shows both.

```
@GET
public Response getClientMessage(@Context HttpContext context) {
    // fetch the header values into a multi valued map
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> headerMap = context.getRequest().getRequestHeaders();

    // If the required headers are not found throw a bad request
    //    throw new WebApplicationException(Status.BAD_REQUEST);

    // Setting the headers on the response
    return Response.ok()
        .header("X-AppEngine-Country", "US")
        .header("X-AppEngine-City", "California").build();
}
```

Hope this helps.